# Multi labeled image classification with imbalanced data, how to split it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-analysis, imbalanced-data

I am working multi labeled image classification. This is my data frame:

[UPDATED]
[image]

As you can see images labeled with 26 features. "1" means exist, "0" means not exist.

My problem is in many of label has imbalanced data. For example:

```
[1] train_df.value_counts('Eyeglasses')

Output:

Eyeglasses
0    54735
1     1265
dtype: int64

[2] train_df.value_counts('Double_Chin')

Output:
Double_Chin
0    55464
1      536
dtype: int64
```

How can I split it  both of for training and validation data as a balanced?

[UPDATE]

I tried to

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
smote = SMOTE()
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
                                                        random_state=42)

X_train_smote, y_train_smote = smote.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)
```

> ValueError: Imbalanced-learn currently supports binary, multiclass and
> binarized encoded multiclasss targets. Multilabel and multioutput
> targets are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Your question mixes two concepts: splitting a multi-class, multi-label image dataset into subsets which have proportional representation, and resampling methods to deal with class imbalance. I am going to focus on just the splitting part of the problem, since that's what the title is about.

I would use a stratified-shuffle-split so to make sure that each subset has equal reprentation. Here's a handy visual for stratified sampling from Wikipedia:

[image: Stratified Sampling example. Source: Wikipedia]

For this I recommend [`skmultilearn`](http://scikit.ml/index.html)'s [`IterativeStratification`](http://scikit.ml/api/skmultilearn.model_selection.iterative_stratification.html) method. It supports multi-label datasets.

```py
    from skmultilearn.model_selection.iterative_stratification import IterativeStratification

    stratifier = IterativeStratification(
        n_splits=2, order=2, sample_distribution_per_fold=[1.0 - train_fraction, train_fraction],
    )
    # this class is a generator that produces k-folds. we just want to iterate it once to make a single static split
    # NOTE: needs to be computed on hard labels.
    train_indexes, everything_else_indexes = next(stratifier.split(X=img_urls, y=labels))

    # s3url array shape (N_samp,)
    x_train, x_else = img_urls[train_indexes], img_urls[everything_else_indexes]
    # labels array shape (N_samp, n_classes)
    Y_train, Y_else = labels[train_indexes, :], labels[everything_else_indexes, :]
```

I wrote a more complete solution, including unit tests, in [a blog post](https://www.richarddecal.com/2020-11-22-Howto-stratified-splitting-Multiclass-Multilabeled-image-classification-dataset/).

One downside with `skmultilearn` is that it is not very well maintained and has some broken functionality. I documented a few of these sharp corners and gotchas in my blog post. Also note that this stratification procedure is painfully slow when you get to several million images because the stratifier only uses a single CPU.

Comment: I tried to your code, but it's cause to out of ram, even with shape of everything_else_indexes (500,26)  and img_urls (500,). I updated my question which is you can see my dataframe. Also  your visual explanation is not make sense because i can't split values, for example if x label is imbalanced and y label is balanced, i can't stratified them, because they are effect another labels. If i am wrong, pls correct me.

Comment: @claymorehack I am not sure what it means to have balanced x labels but imbalanced y labels.

Comment: I have totaly 26 features. As you can see in df.png where in question, every image has these features, and i have totally 15000 images. In total, most of features are imbalenced, for example The "Big_Nose"  feature has {0: 14234, 1: 766} also The "Doubly_Chin" feature has {0: 7800, 1: 7200}. The problem is every feature is related with each other, therefore it's not make sense stratified them. If i try to stratified the positive "Big_Nose" features, maybe i can now face up with the imbalenced "Doubly_Chin" . If i am wrong, pls correct me.

Comment: So your `x` are the images themselves, and the `y` are the rest of the columns (your features). The problem you are describing with related features is a common situation in multi-label datasets, and using `IterativeStratification` with `order=2` will take multiple labels into account while stratifying. There are more details and lecture videos in the `skmultilearn` docs: http://scikit.ml/api/skmultilearn.model_selection.iterative_stratification.html

Comment: Ok, i understand now, but tricky side is my ram (16GB) is not enough even if the small data.

Comment: @claymorehack have you tried using numpy arrays instead of pandas, and closing out browser tabs and other programs that occupy RAM?

Comment: I did what you said but it's still out of ram.